# How to build Vue 3 Component in .net core application?

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, vue-component, razor-pages

I know this is not the traditional way to used Vue.  However, I had to work on a .dotnet core razor pages project that uses Vue via CDN.  In Vue 2, I would build component like this:

```js
    <script type="text/javascript">
            Vue.component('card', {
                template: '#cardTemplate',
                props: {    
                    title: '',
                    subtitle: '',
                    message: ''
                },
                
            });
    </script>
```

```html
<script type="text/x-template" id="cardTemplate">
    <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="344">
   ...
  </v-card>
    </script>
```

Whenever I need it, I would inject it in a razor page.

```
<partial name="~/Pages/View/Product.cshtml"/>
```

Now, I'm looking to upgrade Vue2 to Vue3 and can't get the component to work.

I tried to build it like this but it won't work.

```js
 <script type="vue-template" id="product-display">
    <div><h1>{{name}}<h1></div>
  </script>
   <script>
      Vue.createApp().component('product-display',{
        template: '#product-display',
         props: {
                name: ''
        },
    
    })
   </script>
```

BTW, the const app = Vue.createApp({}) app.mount('#app') is in the layout page same as Vue2 version.  Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated. I've spent a few days on this but can't get it to work.

Comment: Based on the snipit [here:](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/frameworks/react/vue+3+create+component+programmatically) it looks like it should be totally possible.  So I wonder if you just have a syntax error somewhere.  Sadly I don't think I can go to Vue3 yet because it looks like it's CDN file https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.5/dist/vue.global.js is ES6 and I need to be compatible with older ES5 browsers on tablets that can't easily update their browser.